# Running test cluster cassandra/dse on minimal hardware?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I recently came across some of these rugged computers that one of my predecessors had left in our office.  Unfortunately they appear to be maxed out at 4GB RAM, and single core 2.67 GHz processors.

There are four of them, and my first thought was to create a test environment that would mimic our production environment, albeit on a MUCH smaller scale due to hardware (obviously).

I guess my question is will this work, or be a waste of time?  In the datastax enterprise documentation a minimum of 16 GB of RAM is recommended (with an 8G heap), however the recommendation is for production.  Has anyone run a small little test cluster on minimal hardware before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can run a test cluster on such hardware. Check this out: [Multi-Datacenter Cassandra on 32 Raspberry Pi’s](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/32-node-raspberry-pi-cassandra-cluster)

Of course you will need to give it a much smaller heap size and new generation size too, and of course if you give it a heavy load, it will OOM most likely. But you can still run it under a light loads.